# React + Flux example | Step by Step Guide

Tags: reactjs, store, flux, dispatch

I have googled across various platforms and websites but could not find a basic example of flux architecture with react. There are complex examples and even those mentioned simple are difficult to start with. How to start learning flux from docs as is not the best way to understand unless we have a sample working example with step by step guide

Answer (score 2):

Most Flux tutorials you will find online will be using React. You have plenty of options available online. Here are a few (free and paid):

**Free options include:**

https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-to-know-flux-the-react-js-architecture

For a more in depth discussion on this topic you can check out:
https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/whats-the-best-flux-tutorial/51/2

**Paid options include (free trial available):**

With an account on pluralsight there are 4 courses available:

- "Building Applications with React and Flux", by Cory House
- "Building Data-driven React Applications with Relay, GraphQL, and Flux", by Samer Buna
- "Building a Real-time App with React, Flux, Webpack, and Firebase", by Hendrik Swanepoel
- "React and Flux for Angular Developers", by Tony Alicea

Personally, I recommend Cory House's course titled "Building Applications with React and Flux". The course is an easy, slow paced, code as you go style of teaching.

You can get a 30-day free trial on pluralsight.

Finally, Egghead also has a course titled "Browse the React: Flux Architecture (ES5)", by Joe Maddalone.

You can also get a free trial at EggHead.

Comment: I already followed the scotch and discuss.reactjs.org but not to much avail.
I guess I need to try the pluralsight options